# "Failed to load module script" error Live Server - Chrome

Tags: javascript, npm, module, mime-types

I'm trying to use Three.js and Ammo.js in my JavaScript project and have installed them via npm. I'm using them with type module:

```
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but
> the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type
> checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

The above error in the console points to node_modules/ammo.js/ and node_modules/three/.

I tried using the following script tag, which I found on my extensive and tearful search on the internet:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

And the error went away, but now I'm getting this error:

> caught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I'm importing THREE like this:

```
import * as THREE from '../node_modules/three';
import { DragControls } from '/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/DragControls.js';
import Ammo from '/node_modules/ammo.js';
```

I'm running my project on VScode with Live Server and accessing it on Chrome.

I'm not sure what to do next. Can anyone help me out with this? It's driving me crazy as I need to deliver this project to my professor soon.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!